# After Stack Overflow questions page are changed - favorite tagged questions link stopped working!

Tags: support, tags, bookmarks, new-nav

I don't know whether this question already asked before few days ago or not!

But recently Stack overflow has changed its questions pages so now I could not find my favorite tags questions properly.

Before I have bookmarked one link that was redirecting me to my favorite tagged question. It was populating one by one with ajax call, now it has stopped working for me.

Below Link,

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&tagFilter=favorite&pageSize=50
```

If anybody knows the new link instead of above that redirects me to my favorite tagged question it would be great for me.

If you think it's duplicate of some other question - then first check the date of that question - as I know this change made recently before few days back.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268787/245360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you ask is this one: [`https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered?tab=mytags`](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered?tab=mytags). It isn't available from the UI (yet) as far as I know. You can add it as custom tab for the time now.

I am not sure if this is supposed to come back, the team said they want to restore 'old' URLs before rolling out the new navigation. I doubt if that will be a full conversion, since the release candidate is out already and a lot of this is still broken...