# Add a "favorite tags" tab in the new navigation

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, new-nav

I think it will be very useful if there is an easy way to navigate to the unanswered questions with your favorite tags. It should link to [`https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered?tab=mytags`](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered?tab=mytags) for Stack Overflow (the only site the latest release is available now).

Can this be added?

Comment: @tripleee That question (as noted in my comment) is about favorite *questions* (i.e. starred posts). This question is about favorite *tags*.

Comment: @kylestrand Ack, sorry; caseless reading.

Comment: @tripleeee That's okay; that's why I tried to clarify, and why I edited this one's title!